# Stripe implementation in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I need to implement Stripe payment gateway in one of my application, is there any plugin or something I can use to add card and charge customers for some service. If anyone having any references please suggest.
I have gone through some tutorials and plugin but none of them are as per my requirement some plugin allows only to add a card but I am unable to find the plugin that can manage payments with the Stripe.

Comment: Seems there is a plugin for stripe https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stripe_payment. Take a look here.

Comment: Already checked this plugin and it lets you add card only, I need to process the payment also. Actually, I have gone through a lot of plugins but did not find any useful resources.

Comment: @RSSingh did you completed integration of stripe payment in flutter.

Comment: Ravi did you find the solution to charge actually from a card?

Comment: Yes, I managed to charge the customer using the card token and customer ID through their APIs on the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After successfully adding card, you will get a response with a token.

Pass that token to your backend server, you could call charge.create(it depends on your backend language, check [stripe documentations](https://stripe.com/docs/charges)) function to make the actual charge and other stuff.

Comment: while using fire store how can we charge from a user?

Comment: Hi, can I know how to add card? Because I saw the documentation is StripeSource.addSource() but this is outdated

Comment: Any updates on this? How can we add cards from the updated documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use stripe_payment plugin

Here is an article showing you how to do implement payment in flutter using firebase and stripe

https://medium.com/@info_4766/build-a-marketplace-in-your-flutter-app-and-accept-payments-using-stripe-and-firebase-59f074201718

Answer (score 0):

This is best done in Firebase using cloud functions, rather than from the app. Find links below for more info on how to do this:

- https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeyxolsJ3aE
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrLTF4QdRrM

For these reasons:

1. There's the security aspect and one of these links explains it's not a great idea to have your stripe secret inside your client.
2. I want to be able to make this available from flutterweb, as well as other devices. Flutterweb is currently not yet supported by any plugin. The plugin that's best evolved and most used is https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment. Flutter-web has not been released yet (more, see https://github.com/jonasbark/flutter_stripe_payment/pull/147)